# Values of a column in Pandas as columns while keeping the last update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas dataframe.

```
timestamp label value
1          a     1
2          b     2
3          a     5
4          b     0
5          c     3
```

Is there a way to convert the values of the *label* column into columns and keep the last used data as values? It does not matter if I assign Null or 0 in the missing values that have not appeared yet.

```
timestamp  a   b     c
1          1   Null  Null
2          1   2     Null
3          5   2     Null
4          5   0     Null
5          5   0     3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html?highlight=pivot_table#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) and [forward filling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

```
df.pivot_table(index="timestamp", columns="label", values="value").fillna(method="ffill")
```

**Output**

```
label        a    b    c
timestamp               
1          1.0  NaN  NaN
2          1.0  2.0  NaN
3          5.0  2.0  NaN
4          5.0  0.0  NaN
5          5.0  0.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
df.set_index(['timestamp','label'])['value'].unstack().ffill()
```

---

```
label        a    b    c
timestamp               
1          1.0  NaN  NaN
2          1.0  2.0  NaN
3          5.0  2.0  NaN
4          5.0  0.0  NaN
5          5.0  0.0  3.0
```